# How to enable remote access for Synology DSM 4.3 device through Linksys EA6900

Tags: port-forwarding, home-networking, internet-connection, synology

I asked [this question on the synology forum](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=145&t=81626&p=307060), and no offense, but I'm not sure that I trust the answers so am posting here.

I have a Synology DiskStation DS413j running DSM 4.3. I also have a Linksys EA6900 (AC1900). The DiskStation is on my home network on 192.168.1.100.

According to [the Synology docs](http://www.synology.com/en-uk/support/tutorials/456) and [router support compatibility list](http://www.synology.com/en-uk/support/router), I cannot use the EZ-Internet tool to automatically configure remote access. (However I am still within the 90 day risk free trial of the router and can exchange it, which is why I am asking this question.)

My ISP is Time Warner Cable, and I have a residential roadrunner account without a static IP. My IP very rarely changes, but according to the ISP, can at any time.

I tried following the instructions for both devices to set up port forwarding so that I could access DSM over my public IP address. I enabled port forwarding on the router to forward port 5000 to 5000 on 192.168.1.100.

However when I visit http://my.pub.lic.ip:5000 in a browser, I get the following response (from raw tab of fiddler):

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Content-Length: 134
Server: Arris/1.0 UPnP/1.0 miniupnpd/1.0

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not Found</H1>The requested URL was not found on this server.</BODY></HTML>
```

Many other ports at the same public IP do not return a response at all, so I am wondering: where is this response coming from? My router, or the disk station? Or is it possibly from the ISP that assigns me my IP?

My goal is to set up the disk station so that I can access DSM remotely. Do I need to forward more than just 5000 to do this?

Comment: Don't do this as it's a major security risk. Use OpenVPN or Tailscale instead.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe that I didn't realize this, but the cable modem from the ISP is an Arris TG862. I found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crWzQbo-BFI) that showed me how to finally fix this. Had to change the modem to run in bridged mode, then turn off the firewall. After that I got a different IP, but was able to get to my router's admin page, and ultimately DSM, using the IP.

Comment: This question was bumped to the front page because there is **no accepted** solution yet. (You can accept your won answers).